# Magento CSV Import Recreating Existing Product

Tags: php, csv, magento

I have an existing `Magento` site with a little over `1,000 SKU's`. I exported a `CSV` of the product data by going to `System --> Import/Export --> Expor`t and downloading the resulting `CSV`.

I then modified the `CSV` with my data chances and attempt to re import it. `Magento` finds no errors in the file and allows me to upload the `CSV`,

however, some existing products are kept in the database and an identical new product (include the same `SKU`) is created alongside it.

Has anyone ran into this issue before or know of any debugging steps I can take to resolve it? Any information would be sincerely appreciated as I am desperate to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether or not your store is in maintenance mode or not, sometimes the `CRON` job doesn't process successfully, so you might have to Flush `Magento Cache` and `Flush Cache Storage` to get the old products to disappear.

When importing, make sure you select "`Replace`" for the Input Behavior, otherwise it will create duplicate listings even with the same `SKU`.

Source: `350,000+ SKUs on 3 Magento Stores.`

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply, @Brxxn. Unfortunately, the issue is still occurring with "Replace" as the input behavior and following all caches being cleared. Regardless, I really appreciate the advice.